# How Insert Shared Preferences inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have a problem when I insert sharedpreferences inside my fragment, the problem is the context: `this`.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {


@BindView(R.id.tvResultNama)
TextView tvResultNama;

SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

public SettingsFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);

    tvResultNama.setText(sharedPrefManager.getSPNama());
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass activity context and put everything before the return.

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(getActivity());
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your onviewcreated or you could crash on some devices due to a null pointer exception

SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(getActivity());